# How to search Spotify API for tracks with a specific genre

Tags: web-applications, spotify

I'm trying to find a list of tracks from a specific year with a given genre. There doesn't seem to be any documentation on finding a track by genre.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the genre in the `q` param, separated by a space: `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=year:1958%20genre:"classical"&limit=50`